# string interpolation does not work in function definition

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

when I try this string interpolation syntax:

```
(1 to 100).map( vvv => s"{ \"key name\": $vvv, \"value name\": 2 }" )
```

the scala compiler gave me this error:

```
Error:(23, 58) value key is not a member of String
(1 to 100).map( vvv => s"{ \"key name\": ${vvv}, \"value name\": 2 }" )
```

What is going wrong here?
                                                         ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaped quotation marks are invalid in single line string interpolations:

```
scala> s"\""
<console>:1: error: unclosed string literal
       s"\""
           ^
```

Use multi line string literals instead:

```
(1 to 100).map( vvv => s"""{ "key name": $vvv, "value name": 2 }""" )
```

Comment: Is it a [bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476) and this is the workaround or there's some documentation about this?

Comment: My personal opinion is that it is a bug, but the interpretation chosen by the principals is that it’s not problematic enough (and has a work-around) so it’s been declared “won’t fix.” Perhaps they can be persuaded to change their mind some day…

Comment: A change might still get through to add more info to the error message, see test case here https://github.com/som-snytt/scala/commit/54290f2ec25070e08dc7f9f1ce46d8d2b7264531  For the case where it survives compilation, messages for other escape errors have improved.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply done normally like,

> (1 to 10).map( vvv => "{ \"key name\":"+ vvv +", \"value name\": 2 }"
>   )

OR

As pointed by sschaef,

> (1 to 100).map( vvv => s"""{ "key name": $vvv, "value name": 2 }"""